# How to replace numbers in a string by their rounded values, in Julia

Tags: regex, replace, julia

Given a string, say, `-123.456789/EI + 2345.678901/EA`. How could I replace the numbers inside the string by their rounded values to have something like: `-123.46/EI+2345.7/EA`?
Here is what I tried in Julia (but failed):

```
julia> string1="-123.456789/EI + 2345.678901/EA";
julia> replace(string1,r"(-?\d+\.?\d*|-?\d*\.?\d+)",
          round(parse(matchall(r"(-?\d+\.?\d*|-?\d*\.?\d+)",string1))));
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try defining your own function like `function f(x) // round(parse(x)) // end` and then use `replace(string1, f)`

Comment: I tried and got the following error message: ERROR: MethodError: `replace` has no method matching replace(::ASCIIString, ::Function)
Closest candidates are:
  replace(::Union{ASCIIString,UTF8String}, ::Any, ::Any, ::Integer)
  replace(::AbstractString, ::Any, ::Any)
  replace(::AbstractString, ::Any, ::Any, ::Integer)

Comment: Perhaps the regex could be shorter? F.e. `replace(string1,r"\d+\.\d+", x -> round(parse(x),2))`

Comment: It also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest options is to use anonymous function, e.g.:

```
julia> replace(string1,r"(-?\d+\.?\d*|-?\d*\.?\d+)", x -> round(parse(Float64, x), 2))
"-123.46/EI + 2345.68/EA"

julia> replace(string1,r"(-?\d+\.?\d*|-?\d*\.?\d+)", x -> @sprintf("%.2f", parse(Float64, x)))
"-123.46/EI + 2345.68/EA"
```

Examples are for Julia 0.6.2.

Comment: Great!! Thank you a lot. By the way, how can I have the rounded values with the fixed number of digits? For example, I want to express 2345.678901 as 2346 (with 4 reserved places) but not 2345.68.

Comment: `@sprintf` accepts C-style formats. This should be enough for most use cases. A Python-like formatting is provided in https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl.